# Problems in validating fields with same name using BootstrapValidator plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

For most of my website I'm using the Bootstrap 3 framework. In my form I have four different form-groups to validate, the first two work well with the plugin, where validate a name and an email address. Now Bootstrap 3 has a feature where you can use buttons as checkboxes or radio. I want to use the radio button feature. Upon filling in the form and choosing an option from the radio field, I should get success feedback.It works if I don't choose any option and click submit, I get the error feedback and message but it doesn't work for success. 
I'm followed an example from bootstrapValidator website, I can't see any differences in my form from the example. I'm not sure if I should have another plugin or something. 
http://bv.doc.javake.cn/examples/#fields-with-same-name

Here's my code and plugins I'm using curently:

<"http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">
<"http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js">
    <"http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js">
    <"http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.3/css/bootstrapValidator.min.css">
    <"http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.3/js/bootstrapValidator.min.js">

```
<form id="rsvpform" method= "POST" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Name: </label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Enter Full Name" required></input>
            </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <p>Your email address will only be visible to the couple</p>
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Email: </label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Enter an e-mail address" required></input>
            </div>
    </div>
    <p>Will you be attending?</p>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-xs-3 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-xs-9">
        <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-default">
            <input type="radio" autocomplete="off" name="attending" value="Yes" /> Yes
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-default">
            <input type="radio" autocomplete="off" name="attending" value="No" /> No
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-default">
            <input type="radio" autocomplete="off" name="attending" value="Not Sure" /> Not Sure
        </label>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <p>Who are you related to?</p>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-xs-3 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-xs-9">
            <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                    <label class="btn btn-default">
                            <input type="radio" autocomplete="off" name="family" value="Bride" />Bride
                    </label>
                    <label class="btn btn-default">
                            <input type="radio" autocomplete="off" name="family" value="Groom" />Groom
                    </label>
                    <label class="btn btn-default">
                        <input type="radio" autocomplete="off" name="family" value="Friend" />Friend
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">        
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-6">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#rsvpform').bootstrapValidator({
        message: 'This value is not valid',
        feedbackIcons: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
    },
    // Since the Bootstrap Button hides the radio and checkbox
    // We exclude the disabled elements only
    fields: {
        name: {
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'Your full name is required and cannot be empty'
                },
                stringLength: {
                    min: 2,
                    message: 'Your name should be longer than two characters'
                }
            }
        },
        email: {
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'An email address is required and cannot be empty'
                },
                emailAddress: {
                    message: 'This email address is not valid'
                }
            }
        },
        excluded: ':disabled',
        attending: {
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'Are you even attending?'
                }
            }
        },
        family: {
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'Please state your relation to the couple'
                   }
               }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: why are you including two different version of jquery?

Comment: I created a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/silviagreen/jyrc44bc/ but I cannot understand where is your problem

Comment: oh my bad, did not see this, i used an old copy of a website a built a while back.. thanks very much, i would not have seen it.. soon as i took it off, it began working properly lol.. you guys are such geniuses .

Comment: how do i give you a vote up?

Comment: Nice question, in this case I think you can simply vote up the comment that helped you; anyway I'm glad to be helpful!